# Smart pointers to derived types in polymorphic class hierarchies, compilation error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, polymorphism, c++17, smart-pointers

Consider the following framework of my class's interface. I'm presenting two cases, one using `shared_ptr<T>` and the other using `unique_ptr<T>`. The instantiable user-defined types are non-templates. Only the base constructor is templated in that it needs to know the derived type to store a pointer to it. I'm not showing the standard library for checking to see if the template argument is a derived type of the parent class to make the code simpler and easier to read.

```
class Foo;

template<typename DerivedType>
class Base {
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<DerivedType> derived_ptr_{nullptr};
    Foo internal_object_{};
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};

    std::shard_ptr<DerivedType> derived_ptr() { return derived_ptr_; }
    Foo* { return &internal_object_; }

    virtual void initialize(/*.../*) = 0;
    virtual void create(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual void copyTo(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual void update(/*...*/) = 0;
    virtual void cleanup() = 0;

protected:
    Base() = default;
};
```

---

```
class Derived : public Base<class Derived> {
public:
    virtual ~Derived() = default;
    Derived() = default;

    virtual void initialize(/*.../*) override {/*...*/};
    virtual void create(/*...*/) override{
        /*...*/

        // After all creation is successful!
        derived_ptr_ = std::make_shared<Derived>(*this);
    };

    virtual void copyTo(/*...*/) override{/*...*/};
    virtual void update(/*...*/) override{/*...*/};
    virtual void cleanup() override{/*...*};
}
```

The above compiles. I have not tested it for linkage or runtime but it compiles.

---

Now let's consider case two, everything is exactly the same as above, except all instances of `std::shared_ptr<T>` is replaced with `std::unqiue_ptr<T>` being the member variable within the base class, the getter, and the assignment or creation of the smart pointer using `ptr = std::make_unique<T>(*this)`. Except in the case of the `std::unique_ptr<T>` compilation within Visual Studio 2017 with compiler language flag set to `/std:c++latest`that generates this compiler error:

**Note:** -- *The name of the classes in my project are Buffer and VertexBuffer respectively. That's one of the only main difference from what you are seeing from the example above. That and I took them out of their namespaces for simplicity. I also removed the checking of the template parameter to make sure its argument type is a derived type to the base class.*

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Force Engine, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Buffer.cpp
1>c:\users\..\buffer.h(62): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'VertexBuffer' to 'std::unique_ptr<BufferClassType,std::default_delete<_Ty>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            BufferClassType=VertexBuffer,
1>            _Ty=VertexBuffer
1>        ]
1>c:\users\...\buffer.h(62): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>Done building project "Force Engine.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

I'm curious as to why it compiles in the case of `std::shared_ptr<T>` but fails to compile in the case of `std::unique_ptr<T>`. What is causing it to fail, how to resolve this, and is there a way to work around this. I know I can use `std::shared_ptr` and pass that back to a caller that needs it, but I don't particularly want the 'reference' count for this pointer. I would like for the parent class to (own) the pointer of the derived class while providing an interface to allow outside callers to have access to it. In the context of an observer or having the option of creating their own pointer, but never being the owner of the object. The class or classes that would contain instances of the derived class would own the derived class itself but not its internal pointer. Does this compiler error pertain to the fact that `unique_ptr`s can not be copied or such?

Comment: Why do you want to have a `Derived` have (via `Base<Derived>`) a `unique_ptr` to *another* `Derived`?  It seems like there may be some deeper confusion here.

Comment: @Davis Herring, kind of but not really. It was getting late that night and I was just trying to get the shell of the interface for that class done. Being that I was a bit tired, I was overthinking it and started to forget or overlook some of the basics. I was just trying to have a way for the base class to keep track of the derived type so that if I was to implement assignment operators - copy constructors that some derived types can be directly mapped to another where others would need special handling...

Comment: @DavisHerring If I wasn't overthinking it, I could have just used a basic public enumeration within declared in the base which is simple and straight forward. Yet I wanted to also provide an easy way for external objects who would own an instance of the derived "buffer" classes to easily be able to use its pointer method to expose its state to other classes who don't own it. Kind of like view it and getting the contents of, but not being able to manipulate it directly nor control the lifetime of the buffer objects. I was trying to couple both concepts into one thing...

Comment: @DavisHerring As for the question itself, it was a legit question. It pertained to why there was a compiler error being generated in the use of `unique_ptr` and not with `shared_ptr`. I suspected that it had to do with the `unique_ptr` being non-copyable. I just wanted clarity and reassurance of it. When I begin to work on this project again, I might even do a completely different design. I'm going to have to read through the Vulkan docks to see what the expected lifetime of a VkBuffer object is within different contexts of use, such as with VertexBuffers, IndexBuffers, UniformBuffers, etc...

Comment: @DavisHerring Then it's a matter of where they are being used. Are they being used with the back-buffer of the Swapchain, are they being used within the pipeline for a specific shader, are they being used with pre or post rendering processes, are they being used with geometry or compute shaders, or some other effects. So I'm just trying to make the buffer classes simple yet versatile. There's a good amount of boilerplate code in setting up Vulkan objects. Once the underlying core components of the back, middle, and frontend of the renderer are completed, then it becomes much simpler...

Answer (score 2):

`std::make_unique<Derived>(*this)` attempts to copy-construct an instance of `Derived`. But `Derived` is not copyable, because its base class `Base<Derived>` is not copyable, because its data member `std::unique_ptr<DerivedType> derived_ptr_` is not copyable, because `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.

With `shared_ptr`, everything is copyable and the code works.

Comment: That makes sense, it's almost like a circular include with header files due to the nature of unqiue_ptr being non-copyable. So, it appears that I might have to stick with share_ptr, but I don't really want any callers to share in the ownership... and don't want the reference count... Maybe I could just store a raw pointer of the derived within the base, and then have a method that just returns a unique_ptr... but not sure if that would work as I'm intending. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: It makes little sense for an object to store an owning pointer to itself (or a shared pointer, for that matter). Who really owns that object? *They* should be holding a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I was thinking on the lines of the base class holding a pointer to the derived class. The reason for this thinking is, let's say I have 3 classes driver A,B, & C. Let's say A and B are fully compatible with each other so that I could practically do A = B and everything maps from on to the other, but let's say C has a slight variation. You couldn't do A = C or B = C without some extra logic and this is where the base class owning pointer would come in. Just check and compare the pointers before trying to perform the assignment operator. There might be other methods of doing this...

Comment: Also, I thought it would be a nice way for a caller class to have access to it via a return function. Not an owner of it, but an observer. Right now, this is only a prototype for the interface. I may redesign it. I've been experimenting with several designs.

Comment: You are using CRTP. The usual way for a base class in CRTP to obtain a pointer to derived class is `static_cast<DerivedType*>(this)`

Comment: I guess I could do away with this, remove the template itself, and just require that all derived class implements a method to return a unique_ptr<T> and just use the class's `*this`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I was trying to stay away from casting if possible. The code is going to be used in a rendering pipeline. I'm looking for high efficiency. Less overhead, yet quick and easy access. It's part of a Vulkan application.

Comment: `static_cast<DerivedType*>(this)` is zero overhead at runtime, or a single machine instruction at worst. Certainly as cheap or cheaper than reading the value of a data member.

Comment: True, a static_cast doesn't take much, a dynamic_cast might take a little more effort as it has to search through the heap instead of the stack, but it is still efficient. I was starting to become tired and I tend to overlook or forget some of the basics when I get like that...